# Migrating Data on Heroku Pipeline Promotion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, data-migration, heroku-pipelines

I'm using a pipeline for my rails app on Heroku. I have a staging app, which is then promoted to a production app. I run any schema migrations before deploying to staging and the slug is then moved to production when I promote it.

But now need I to migrate some user data on my next deploy, and I'm looking for a way to do this as part of the promotion. I could always run a rake task when the promotion is complete, but that seems very risky. Ideally, the code should run before the app is released, and rollback if anything goes wrong.

I thought that [Release Phases](https://blog.heroku.com/announcing-release-phase-run-tasks-before-new-release-deployed) were the answer, but I don't think I can access user data there, given [these considerations](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase#design-considerations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that my reservations about [Release Phases](https://blog.heroku.com/announcing-release-phase-run-tasks-before-new-release-deployed) were unfounded. You can migrate data just fine as part of a release phase. For anyone else trying the same thing, I used the [data_migrate](https://github.com/ilyakatz/data-migrate) ruby gem, which works very well. I then updated my Procfile to include the following:

```
release: rails db:migrate:with_data
```

This runs any data migrations that I've created with the gem, and if anything goes wrong there, the release is aborted.